# I can return the src, alt, and setsrc of the img, but I can't get the title and height values, why?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is a very simple piece of code that I wrote

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.zcool.com.cn/discover/607!0!0!0!0!!!!2!-1!1')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

imgs = soup.select('.work-list-box img')

for img in imgs:
    print(img['src'])
    print(img['title'])
```

The error message is KeyError: 'title'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that not every element in the array `imgs` has a `title`.
@Ankit Jaiswal suggested to use the `get` function which is way better than a try and except.

```
for img in imgs:
    img.get('src', 'default')
    img.get('title', 'default')
```

Just modify the `'default'` with what you want to return in case that key doesn't exist.

Comment: I think continue is better...Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Exceptions are not the way to handle such cases, it would be better to check if the key exists in conditions or even better use `dict.get(key, 'default')`

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal, thanks a lot for the comment. It is indeed a way better way of getting the keys than trying to do a try/except block.

Comment: Thank you！Check that there are some imgs that do not have title attributes